# How to disable ion-select using typescript. ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I can disable ion-select using disable attribute like the following:

```
<ion-item>       
      <ion-label stacked>Property Type</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="propType" (ionChange)="ionChanger()" disabled="true" >
              <ion-option value="{{ptype}}" *ngFor="let ptype of PropTypeArray">{{ptype}}</ion-option>                 
          </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

How can i disable from typescript file? I tried the following command but no luck

In my type script file

```
  disableSelector:boolean

    constructor(){
       this.disableSelector = true;
    }
```

here is in the html file

```
disabled = "disableSelector"
```

totally cannot work at all

best Rgds,
frog

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using **`disableSelector`** variable so you need to use it with **`[disabled]`** property binding as shown below,

```
<ion-item>       
      <ion-label stacked>Property Type</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="propType" 
                      (ionChange)="ionChanger()" 

                      [disabled]="disableSelector" >  //<<< This is required.

           <ion-option value="ptype"                  //<<< removed {{}} braces.
                      *ngFor="let ptype of PropTypeArray">
                             {{ptype}}
          </ion-option>    
       ...             
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that as of Ionic v3.4 `[disabled]="true"` does not seem to work. Not even plain `disabled` annotation. And I have the exact same setup as in your code above.

Comment: Can't say anything on it as don't know IONIC.

Comment: For me on ionic 3.7  it worked   with following code :<ion-select  [(ngModel)]="taskedit.checkLists[i].status"   disabled="true" >